# How do I download a Pandas DataFrame to a CSV File in Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have a large DataFrame that I'd like to explore in Excel and transfer to other applications. How do I download that as a CSV file in my Streamlit App?

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](http://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button#stdownload_button), given you have a DataFrame `my_large_df`, you can write a function:

```py
import streamlit as st

@st.cache
def convert_df_to_csv(df):
  # IMPORTANT: Cache the conversion to prevent computation on every rerun
  return df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')


st.download_button(
  label="Download data as CSV",
  data=convert_df_to_csv(my_large_df),
  file_name='large_df.csv',
  mime='text/csv',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import streamlit as st

my_large_df = pd.read_csv('file.csv') #This is your 'my_large_df'

@st.cache
def convert_df_to_csv(df):
  # IMPORTANT: Cache the conversion to prevent computation on every rerun
  return df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')

st.download_button(
  label="Download data as CSV",
  data=convert_df_to_csv(my_large_df),
  file_name='large_df.csv',
  mime='text/csv',
)
```